# Partition of [3n] into summoids

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $ [n] $ be the set $ \{1,2,\ldots n\}$.

A *summoid* is a subset $ A \subset [n] $ of the form $ \{a,b,a+b\} $ (you can choose a better name, if it doesn't exist already).

Now, I developed by accident this simple result:

> There is no partition of $ [9] $ into (disjoint) summoids.

I want to ask the following questions:

1. Is it true for general $ [3k] $ when $ k > 1 $? According to a computer program I found that it is true for $ [12] $, but it seems my method for $ [9]$ can't be applied to the general case (maybe my program for $[12]$ isn't trustworthy).
   **According to the comment below by R. van Dobben de Bruyn**, there is no such partition when $ k \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$.
   **According to the comment below by Gerhard Paseman**, there is a counterexample for $ k = 5 $ that extends also to $ n = 3 \cdot 4^k $ and to $ n = 3 \cdot (1+4^k) $.
2. Is it useful for something?
3. Is there any study of such results?

Comment: Just a comment: $[3]$ is itself a summoid, so you should at least assume $k>1$.

Comment: There is a local obstruction at $2$: the sum of the elements of $\{a,b,a+b\}$ is even, hence $\frac{3}{2}k(3k+1)$ (the sum of the elements of $\{1,\ldots,3k\}$) should be even as well. This already proves that there is no such partition when $k \equiv 2, 3 \pmod{4}$. But this argument doesn't tell us anything about the other two cases $k \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: @DanielLitt Thanks, I forgot to include that.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Intersting! I will update it. Thanks

Comment: I get 5,7,12-3,8,11-1,9,10-2,4,6,  and a similar decomposition for n=15.  Perhaps this pattern can be extended for n=24 and 27?  Gerhard "Working From The Inside Out" Paseman, 2017.08.10.

Comment: I can extend this to n =3*4^k  and n+1, but n=3*2^k is a challenge for k odd Perhaps someone can prove it impossible?  Gerhard "Hard To Leave Construction Mode" Paseman, 2017.08.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thanks, I'll update it. What do you mean by $ n + 1 $?

Comment: Shorthand with error. I can do it for 3*4^k and 3*(1+4^k) for positive k.  I prefer to keep symbols to a minimum, so I define a variable and reuse it.  Gerhard "Sort Of Like Macro Programming" Paseman, 2017.08.10.

Comment: I recommend the following for a breadth first search or a constraint solver with n=24. Enumerate all 132 legal triples. Start by picking out one of the 11 triples that has the number 24. Make a copy of the 132 triples minus those that share a number with the picked triple. Recurse until an exact cover is found or no exact cover is possible. My guess is that you can go five triples deep, cover less than a million cases this way, and find most of them can't be continued.  Gerhard "Might Be Short In Python" Paseman, 2017.08.10.

Comment: We can start from the fact that for the partition to be possible $k$ most be $0$ or $1$ mod $4$ since the sum of the right sides must be $3k(3k+1)/4$.

Comment: A002849 at oeis.org.  I'll let you look for further links.  Gerhard "Has Found Enough Sequences Today" Paseman, 2017.08.10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the following results:

- N = 12: 
  (1, 11, 12)
  (3, 7, 10)
  (4, 5, 9)
  (2, 6, 8)
- N = 15:
  (1, 14, 15)
  (3, 10, 13)
  (4, 8, 12)
  (5, 6, 11)
  (2, 7, 9)
- N = 24:
  (1, 23, 24)
  (2, 20, 22)
  (5, 16, 21)
  (6, 13, 19)
  (7, 11, 18)
  (8, 9, 17)
  (3, 12, 15)
- N = 27:
  (1, 26, 27)
  (2, 23, 25)
  (4, 20, 24)
  (7, 15, 22)
  (8, 13, 21)
  (9, 10, 19)
  (6, 12, 18)
  (3, 14, 17)
  (5, 11, 16)

and so on.

My guess would be that there are always (a lot of) solutions for any $k \equiv 0, 1\mod 4$.
In my opinion, this is some kind of Goldbach-ish problem. It is likely to get some probabilistic heuristic, but may be difficult to prove.

---

For reference, here I add the number of different solutions for each $k$.

- N = 12: 8 solutions;
- N = 15: 21 solutions;
- N = 24: 3040 solutions;
- N = 27: 20505 solutions;

and so on.

---

EDIT:

Thanks to OEIS, we now have some reference.

In this paper: http://oeis.org/A104429/a104429.pdf, the existence of solutions is discussed in detail in section I.3 (starting from page 22).

Comment: Check out a284737 at oeis.org.  Does this match up?  Gerhard "It May Be Langford Disguised" Paseman, 2017.08.10.

Comment: A108235 is better.  Gerhard "It Has Some More References" Paseman, 2017.08.10.

Comment: I think a104429 is about arithmetic progressions, not about summoids.  Gerhard "We May Need Different Terminology" Paseman, 2017.08.10.

Comment: Ah, I see it handles both. Gerhard "Thanks For Posting The Link" Paseman, 2017.08.10.